# What does "sense of community" mean?

Tags: phrase-requests, word-usage

Currently, I'm living in HK. But I am Chinese and I know nothing about Cantonese which is the mother tongue of Hongkongers. So, I feel lonely here and I don't think I belong here.

So, can I say **I don't have a 'sense of community' in HK**?

If not, what phrase should I use?

Comment: Hello. That is a perfect expression of your feelings. A sense of community means a feeling of belonging. I hope you develop a community soon. :)

Comment: There is a possibility of the sentence being mistaken to mean that it is **you** do not have the attitude of belonging in the community -- according to the currently accepted definition of the expression 'sense of community' -- it does not mean what you intend to convey. Try another phrase instead.

Comment: What you mean is that you do not **get** a sense of community -- however, I feel one should avoid the confusion and use a better term.

Answer (score 1):

Your expression:

> I don't have a sense of community in Hong Kong

works absolutely fine and is quite natural (I think people from Hong Kong use the abbreviation HK -- but in AmE (my dialect) it is not used).

---

That being said, I don't know if it's the best way to express the feelings you describe after that. So I will offer a few further possible expressions and try to point out the nuances I take each to have.

> I feel lonely here.
>
> I'm having trouble connecting with people in Hong Kong

Your expression regarding *sense of community* to me emphasizes that you do not have a core  group of friends or ties to the community there. If I were me saying it or hearing it, a *yet* on the end would give it a mood that you expect that to change (i.e. optimism).

If you say more bluntly that you *feel lonely*, then it would give me the expectation that you don't expect this situation to change with time.

If you want to emphasize that language and other elements are creating a barrier, then I would recommend the *having trouble connecting* expression.

Given your remark that *I don't think I belong here* (which to me implies that you don't expect to acclimate), I might prefer the construction:

> I feel isolated here and I don't think I can connect with people in Hong Kong since their culture and language differ from my own.